# Node.js skips the functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I building a Discord bot and I want to do a "fight" command. The idea is to fight the bot (the name of my bot is "Il Koala Aiutante", so you fight a koala), you can attack or defend yourself and you have 50% that your action is successful. If it's not, you receive a random amount of damage. Example: if you want to attack, you have the 50% to hit for a random amount of damage.

I try to code it, but idk why, Node.js skips the functions that I declare. The ENTIRE file is uploaded [here](https://srcshare.io/?id=60b51d4f0b940f1e79098401).
Here's a (big) piece of the code

```
 do {
        // console.log('while')
  
        damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5) + 5)
        const msgfilter = m => m.author.id == '835174121708978248' //The id of the bot
  
        async function getMessage () {
          const promise = message.channel.awaitMessages(msgfilter, {
            max: 1
          })
          message.reply('Cosa vuoi fare ?')
          return msg = await promise
        }
  
        getMessage()
  
        async function choose () {
          msg = await getMessage()
          console.log(msg)
          const reactfilter = (reaction, user) => ['⚔', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id == message.author.id
          msg.awaitReactions(reactfilter, {
            max: 1
          })
            .then(collected => {
              console.log('reaction')
              reaction = collected.first().emoji.name
              if (reaction === '⚔') {
                console.log('attack')
                Attack()
              }
              if (reaction === '') {
                console.log('defense')
                defense()
              }
            })
        }
  
        choose()
  
        function Attack() {
          message.reply(PlayerAttacks[0])
          const Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 1) + 1)
          if (Random == 1) {
            message.reply(KoalaDefense[Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0)])
          } else {
            message.reply(`Hai colpito il koala! Gli hai inflitto ${damage} di danno!`)
            KoalaHealth = KoalaHealth - damage
          }
        }
  
        function defense () {
          let Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 1) + 1)
          if (Random == 1) {
            message.reply(KoalaAttacks[Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0)])
            Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 1) + 1)
            if (Random == 1) {
              message.reply(`Il Koala ti ha colpito! Ti ha inflitto ${damage} di danno!`)
              PlayerHealth = PlayerHealth - damage
            } else if (Random == 2) {
              message.reply(PlayerDefense[0])
            }
          } else {
            message.reply('Te e il koala vi guardate intensamente')
          }
        }
      } while (KoalaHealth >= 0 || PlayerHealth >= 0)
```

Comment: "Node.js skips the functions that I declare." a) Be specific, which functions are being "skipped"? b) Try debugging your code on your own first. Add `console.log` statements to various parts of your code to see how far into your code it gets, where it stops, etc. That's a very simple way to see exactly why some of your functions are not getting reached, but you need to attempt this on your own before seeking help from others on StackOverflow. We can try to help you if you're still stuck after attempting this debugging process on your own.

Comment: @Cannicide i tried to do a debug session with the ```console.log```s too as you can see in the code. When I say "skip" I mean that the function even if called doesn't run. I hope you can help me :) Now im rewriting the code btw

Comment: Which functions? `Attack()` and `defense()`? If so, you should put more `console.log` statements within the various parts of those functions (and perhaps also log the value of the `Random` variable after each time its value is set) in order to see exactly what is going on. Let us know what happens (in other words, let us know which `console.log`s are reached and which aren't).